# Finding N random neighbors in radius in 2D

Tags: algorithm, knn, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

Currently, I am tweaking my implementation of [Boids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boids) algorithm.

This algorithm requires fixed-radius near neighbors search. For each boid (it could be 50-100k of them) you want to check all neighbors in some radius (usually it is equal to boid view range).

However, I found that the algorithm works well if I just check not all but just around 30 randomly chosen neighbors. Randomness is key here so k-nearest neighbors algorithm is not ideal.

So I am looking for fast way to find these 30 random neighbors in a given radius. Before I was using KDTree from nanoflann library to perform a fixed radius search. I guess the complexity of such search in the worst case scenario when all boids have the same position is at least O(n). I was wondering if the search of k random neighbors in a given radius can be done with complexity around O(k*log(n)) and if so which algorithm could be used.

Comment: You can use a K-d tree.